# Nutch + HBase: hbase versions issue and java exception

Tags: java, hbase, nutch, restlet, gora

I'm trying to setup Nutch 2.2.1 using HBase 0.94.14, on Debian Squeeze.
I've followed Nutch 1 and 2 tutorials carefully and various documentations. 
I could build HBase 0.94.14, and eventually got it to work (I can create tables etc.)
I could build Nutch without any issue (it's set on Gora 0.3)

Now issues are:
1- when trying to launch Nutch, I get the following trace:

```
./nutch inject /root/nutch/apache-nutch-2.2.1/urls/
InjectorJob: starting at 2014-11-27 09:43:53
InjectorJob: Injecting urlDir: /root/nutch/apache-nutch-2.2.1/urls
InjectorJob: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.gora.memory.store.HBaseStore
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
```

etc.

Using strace -f, I've figured out that "HBaseStore.class" was not found:

```
stat("/root/nutch/apache-nutch-2.2.1/runtime/local/org/apache/gora/memory/store/HBaseStore.class",\
  <unfinished ...>
[pid  1827] <... futex resumed> )       = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
```

I tried to figure out if there was an issue with classpath, but eventually found out that:
- HBaseStore.class was present neither in the Nutch directory tree nor in the Hbase 0.94.4 directory tree
- HBase jar version in the Nutch tree was surprinsingly: hbase-0.90.4.jar

According to some online discussions I found, I replace hbase-0.90.4.jar in the nutch tree with hbase-0.94.4 from the hbase tree...

But:
- it doesn't fix the java issue
- each time I'm rebuilding nutch, hbase-0.90.4.jar is back and I can't find any source for it in the nutch tree :-/

Note that /root/nutch/apache-nutch-2.2.1/conf/hbase-site.xml has:

```
<property>
<name>hbase.rootdir</name>
<value>/root/nutch/hbase-master/conf/</value>
</property>
```

which corresponds to Nutch 0.94.4 ...

Also tried to rebuild and use Gora 0.5 but it makes Nutch build fail.

I'm not an expert in Java at all, and I don't understand why Nutch is not using the correct version of HBase, why it seems there are missing sources and java classes, and at this point I'm totally stuck. What a mess.

Thanks for any tip that could help to save this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have this line in `gora.properties`:

```
gora.datastore.default=org.apache.gora.hbase.store.HBaseStore
```

with special attention to the namespace:

org.apache.gora.**hbase**.store.HBaseStore

and not

org.apache.gora.**memory**.store.HBaseStore

I hope this will fix the issue :)

---

Edit about versions:

About hbase-0.90.4 returning, Gora-0.3 depends on HBase-0.90.4, which is incompatible with HBase-0.94.14.

In order to run with HBase-0.94.14 you have to use Nutch-2.3-SNAPSHOT (called "2.x"). You have a link in [Nutch2Tutorial](http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/Nutch2Tutorial) or you can [svn checkout http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/nutch/branches/2.x/](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/nutch/branches/2.x/)

Nutch 2.3-SNAPSHOT depends on Gora-0.5 which depends on HBase 0.94.14

---

Seems quite solved:

http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/nutch-dev/201412.mbox/%3C548F4F1B.7020206@googlemail.com%3E

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NUTCH-1899

Comment: Hi Alfonso, thanks for your answer!
[edit: see my extra comments below]

Comment: Well, actually it's _above_ ;) I've posted it as a new answer.

Comment: I am confused. I don't see anything new :(

Comment: I've tried to build Nutch 2.3-latest against HBase 0.94.14 but it breaks at:

[ivy:resolve] :::: ERRORS
[ivy:resolve]       restlet: bad module name found in http://maven.restlet.org/org/restlet/jse/  org.restlet.lib.org.restlet.lib.org.json/2.0/org.restlet.lib.org.restlet.lib.org.json-2.0.pom: expected='org.restlet.lib.org.restlet.lib.org.json found='org.restlet.lib.org.json'

/root/nutch/2.3/build.xml:467: impossible to resolve dependencies:
        resolve failed - see output for details

Comment: That is a weird error :P I really don't know how to fix that ivy dependencies issue :( Never happened to me. If I found out I will comment. I use Nutch 2.3-SNAPSHOT + HBase 0.94.14 and works for me. Oh, and Hadoop 1.2.1 ; maybe updating the dependence in ivy.xml to Hadoop-1.2.1?

Comment: Now happened to me! But it seems you are already on the track :) http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/nutch-user/201412.mbox/%3CDUB402-EAS423DA6DFA62509BAE15713A926E0@phx.gbl%3E . Now I am looking forward the solution too :P

Comment: Seems solved here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NUTCH-1899 . You can make the modifications shown in the patch in your local source code (because still is not commited to trunk). Thanks to Sebastian Nagel and Talat Uyarer.

Answer (score 0):

Alfonso,

I checked about gora.properties, it was OK.

Also, I've tried the latest 2.3 Snapshot but unfortunately it ended into some dependency issue at build time:

```
[ivy:resolve]       ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[ivy:resolve]       ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[ivy:resolve]       ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[ivy:resolve]       ::   org.restlet.jse#org.restlet.lib.org.restlet.lib.org.json;2.0:     java.text.ParseException: inconsistent module descriptor file found in 'http://maven.restlet.org/org/restlet/jse/org.restlet.lib.org.restlet.lib.org.json/2.0/org.restlet.lib.org.restlet.lib.org.json-2.0.pom': bad module name: expected='org.restlet.lib.org.restlet.lib.org.json' found='org.restlet.lib.org.json'; 
[ivy:resolve]       ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[ivy:resolve] :::: ERRORS
[ivy:resolve]       restlet: bad module name found in http://maven.restlet.org/org/restlet/jse/  org.restlet.lib.org.restlet.lib.org.json/2.0/org.restlet.lib.org.restlet.lib.org.json-2.0.pom: expected='org.restlet.lib.org.restlet.lib.org.json found='org.restlet.lib.org.json'
[ivy:resolve] 
[ivy:resolve] :: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS

BUILD FAILED
/root/nutch/2.3/build.xml:467: impossible to resolve dependencies:
        resolve failed - see output for details
```

Answer (score 0):

Try updating version number:

- go in the ivy/ivy.xml;
- change the rev="2.2.1" of org="org.restlet.jse" to rev="2.2.3" (occurs 3 times).